# custom action property: how to send a parameter?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to run an exe in custom actions. Already add the exe inside the custom actions.

Now, how can I send a parameter "-i" inside the custom action property?

Answer (score 0):

What type of custom action are you talking about?

In any case:

The function you use for invoking the exe will have a parameter to pass the Command-Line params.

For eg:

CreateProcess in Win32 has an argument for command-line params

LaunchAppAndWait in Installscript has an argument for command-line params

Comment: Inside the custom Action properties window.  I can run the exe under the commit, but I need to pass a "-i" parameter. help me

Answer (score 0):

The Target column of CustomAction table contains command-line parameters.
The actual way to put the parameters there depends on the tool you use to create the installer. E.g. in WiX it would be ExeCommand attribute.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm

For VS setup projects:

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/